# Can a Service access an Activity if it's not active

Tags: android, android-activity, service, background-process

I'm making a MP3 player and I have `ArrayList`s of songs that need to be altered and added to, even while the player is not active or in the background.

Do I store these `ArrayList`s in the `Service` so it can update them when needed, or do I store them in the `Activity` so the UI can access them easier? I've seen tutorials doing it both ways, so I am confused on how to proceed.

I'm thinking that if an `Activity` is not visible or active, the `Service` cannot access them. So, all of the mp3 lists should be stored in the `Service` and bind the `Activity` to the `Service` so the UI can update?

A `Service` can access my other classes while the app is in the background, right?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how you would not have the playlist in the service as it will be destroyed in the Activity much quicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you do all the background actions in the service. This means that all data/information that is necessary to do this action or is related to this action is also managed by the service.
Your activities should only work as view or control possibility of your service.

In your case for example the `PlaylistActivity` will ask the service for the current playlist and will just display it. (Only a view for the service).
The `PlayerActivity` will get the current song playing, the current progress (e.g. in seconds), and the playing state (started/stopped). This information will be displayed in a typical player interface. But it will offer also controls to start or stop the song, jump to next or previous song or e.g. fast forward/backward. If the user clicks these controls it is simply forwarded to the service. (A view and control for the service)

Comment: Thanx thanx so much... You confirmed everything I was thinking... :-)